# Prevent rectangle collisions in Graphics2D?

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel

I'm wondering how I can prevent two squares (drawn in Graphics2D) from intersecting. One of the squares is controllable with WASD, and the other square is stationary.

When I "push" the controllable square up against the stationary square from any side (top, bottom, left, right), I would like the stationary square to act as an obstacle.

```
if ((userYC > (squareList.get(i).y - 50) && userYC < (squareList.get(i).y + 50) && userXC > (squareList.get(i).x - 50) && userXC < (squareList.get(i).x + 50))) {
        brush.drawString("INTRUDING", 10, 125);
}
```

The squares are defined by the X and Y coordinate of their top-left corner, and also  by width and height. I set width and height to be 50. In the code above, I am able to detect when the squares intersect. However, I'm not sure how I can go about preventing them from colliding.

Comment: Just check the collision before moving, and if they're colliding, don't allow the player to move.

Comment: If the player hits the stationary square from above, I would still like to be able to "slide" it from side to side. Wouldn't not allowing the player to move defeat this?

Comment: You want the player to push the other blocks if they collide?

Comment: You know what I actually misunderstood what you first said. I tried rearranging some of the code to fit your suggestion and it works now! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Np. Note though that collision detection is a notoriously difficult thing to do right. If you find that your hand-rolled collision detection is too slow or buggy, you may want to start looking into game libraries/engines to help with the annoying parts of game design.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Carcigenicate helped me figure it out. I ended up predicting collisions whenever I was processing keystrokes, and if they indicated some kind of collision, I just retracted that process.